# While loop fails to find string in array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, while-loop, boolean

I have added to my program a function that allows the user to pick one of the two available languages (English and French). I have also added a list of acceptable inputs:

```
string language;
string LangList[] = { "1", "en", "2", "fr" };

void output(string en, string fr) {
    if (language == "1" || language == "en")
        cout << en;
    else if (language == "2" || language == "fr")
        cout << fr;
    else
        throw "LANGUAGE";
}
```

The `while` loop below is written to repeat itself until `language` is equal to one of the strings in `LangList`.

```
while (true) {
        cout << "(1) ENGLISH, (2) FRANCAIS" << endl;
        cout << "Language number: ";
        cin >> language;
        bool isLangVerified = find(begin(LangList), end(LangList), language);
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        if (isLangVerified) {
            cout << "Language: ";
            output("ENGLISH\n", "FRANCAIS\n");
            break;
        }
        else {
            cout << "ERROR!\n" << endl;
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            cin.clear();
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, the `isLangVerified` turns into `true` even if `language` was not found in `LangList`, causing it to throw an exception.

Comment: You seem to believe that `isLangVerified` will magically update itself when `language` changes. It will not. You calculate it once, and it maintains its value since. I don't see how this loop can ever even call `output`. If you say it does, that means the code you show here is different from the code you actually run.

Comment: it'll never go inside `if (isLangVerified) {` because `isLangVerified` is always false at that point

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thank you for the advice. Updated the code.

Comment: could you paste bin your current main.cpp

Comment: @MegaSniperB http://pastebin.com/Y00pr09r

Comment: @PradanaAumars [`std::find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) doesn't yield a `bool` value.

Comment: Indeed, find returns an iterator. If you want a bool value, compare the find result with end()

Comment: @PradanaAumars http://pastebin.com/PCmGfa4W

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the main problem is that you are trying to set an `iterator` to the `bool isLangVerified`.  I suggest you loop the array and see if the input is stored inside the array.

```
std::array<std::string,4> LangList = { "1", "en", "2", "fr" };
bool isLangVerified = false;

while (true)
{
    std::cout << "(1) ENGLISH, (2) FRANCAIS" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Language number: ";
    std::cin >> language;

    for(int i = 0; i < LangList.size() - 1; i++)
    {
        if(LangList[i] == language)
        {
            isLangVerified = true;
        }
    }

    if (isLangVerified)
    {
        std::cout << "Language: ";
        output("ENGLISH\n", "FRANCAIS\n");
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR!\n" << std::endl;
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        std::cin.clear();
    }
}
```

`std::array<std::string,4> LangList = { "1", "en", "2", "fr" };` allows the use of `LangList.size()` where `std::string LangList[] = { "1", "en", "2", "fr" };` does not.

This would make your final program look like this: http://pastebin.com/PCmGfa4W

Comment: Something is wrong with the syntax of `LangList.size()` in `for(int i = 0; i < LangList.size() - 1; i++)`.

Comment: Never mind it worked using your pastebin code. Thank you!